# Remove img which a part of the src is changing with jsoup

Tags: java, image, jsoup

I would like to remove an img from a html code. This html code is generated by a soft. 
But the src of my img depends on the name of the html document.

For example if the name of my html code is `test.html`
The src img will be

```
<img srx="test_one_way.gif">
```

If the name is `example.html`

The src img will be

```
<img srx="example_one_way.gif">
```

As you see, just a part of the src is changing.

`_one_way.gif` won't change

So my question is :
How can I select(remove) this img ?

To my mind, may be I could select it with : `"name"+_one_way.gif`

I"m parsing the doc like that :

```
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(new FileInputStream(readLine("file name: ")), "ISO-8859-1", "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

But I don't see how I can do it.

Comment: Why not just add an `id` parameter to the `img` to uniquely select it?

Comment: Because as I said the html code is generated by a soft. And I can't control the output of this soft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to select the img using expression in jsoup if you don't assign it a unique parameter:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("img[src$=_one_way.gif");
Element firstElement = elements.first();
```

Then, you can always change an elements attribute:

```
firstElement.attr("src", firstElement.attr("src").replaceFirst("^(.*?)(_one_way\\.gif)$", "$1") + "_one_way.gif");
```